# Create "axis" vectors as compile-time constants

Tags: rust, const-generics

Given a rather simple "small-vector" struct used for graphics or linear algebra:

```
pub struct VecN<T, const N: usize>
{
    v: [T; N],
}
```

How would one create the typical "axis" vectors as *compile-time* constants?
I.e., something along the line of:

```
impl<T> VecN<T, 3> where T: From<f32> + Default
{
    const AXES: [VecN<T, 3>; 3] = [VecN::new([T::from(1.0), T::default(), T::default()]),
                                   VecN::new([T::default(), T::from(1.0), T::default()]),
                                   VecN::new([T::default(), T::default(), T::from(1.0)])];
}
```

(The above does not work since the From and Default traits cannot be evaluated
at compile time.)

At best, the only "workaround" I've found is to create the constants for each
type I'm interested in, e.g.,

```
impl VecN<f32, 3>
{
    const AXES: [VecN<T, 3>; 3] = [VecN::new([1.0, 0.0, 0.0]),
                                   VecN::new([0.0, 1.0, 0.0]),
                                   VecN::new([0.0, 0.0, 1.0])];
}
```

This feels very redundant, even if it can be alleviated pretty easily using
macros. And more exotic types are of course not included. Is there some way to
makes this work in a more generic way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've mentioned, the problem here is that trait methods cannot be evaluted at compile time. However, what *can* be evaluated at compile time are trait *constants*, so you can define a trait with constants for `ZERO` and `ONE`, and use those instead:

```rust
trait ConstNum {
    const ZERO: Self;
    const ONE: Self;
}

impl ConstNum for f32 { .. }
impl ConstNum for f64 { .. }
// etc

impl<T: ConstNum> VecN<T, 3> {
    const AXES: [VecN<T, 3>; 3] = [VecN::new([T::ONE, T::ZERO, T::ZERO]),
                                   VecN::new([T::ZERO, T::ONE, T::ZERO]),
                                   VecN::new([T::ZERO, T::ZERO, T::ONE])];
}
```